# Copyright Infringement Guide

Tags: copyright

I'm thinking of making a website that explains about games (walkthroughs, level-passing guide, etc.) which will include screenshots and the game content. Will these violate some kinds of copyright laws?

Sorry for my bad english explanation. I'm also sorry if this isn't the place for asking such question.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe would generally be considered "[fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)" or "[fair dealing](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/exceptions-to-copyright#fair-dealing)". The details will depend on your jurisdiction, but as a rule courts will look at how much you copied, how you used it, whether you are making a profit, and whether it has a negative impact on the market for the original game.

The trouble with fair use and its relatives is that they don't have any well-defined boundaries: if it ever came to a court case the court would look at the facts of the case and make a judgement about the balance. So making sure you have the balance well-weighted in your favour is important.

Describing the game or how to beat it in your own words is not a problem. E.g. "The boss monster has a vulnerable spot on its right ankle". You own the copyright in your own words, even if you are describing something that is copyrighted by someone else.

Screenshots are generally not a problem, especially if you take them from general gameplay. If you were to copy a publicity shot provided by the publisher then that would be more of an issue.

The more of your own work you put in, the more the balance tilts in your favour. For instance, taking a screenshot of the boss fight, cropping around the boss monster, and putting an arrow labelled "Aim here" is better than just reproducing the whole screenshot.